# How do I get publicly accessible URL from firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

It's really simple: I'm manually uploading files to firebase storage (some pictures that I want to use in my app). I need the public http address, but all I can find there is this type of link `gs://myapp.appspot.com/logo3.png`. How do I get from that to a URL that I can actually use in my browser?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Storage buckets do not have publicly accessible URLs by default.  You have at least two options to get one:

1. Write some code in your app to [get a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) for the content.  I've linked to the instructions for JavaScript, since you haven't indicated the client platform you're working with.
2. If you're just trying to get a static URL without calling an API, you will have to use the Google Cloud console to mark the entire storage bucket as "public", then build URLs to the content as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).